# If #head versionnumber.txt < #head latestversionnumber.txt then: do this

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing

I'm working on automating an update service. I created two text files that just contain the version number.

`versionnumber.txt`:

```
3861
```

`latestversionnumber.txt`:

```
4002
```

How can I compare these two numbers from the different files to create an if/then/else switch? This is being ran through a bash file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
v=$(cat versionnumber.txt)
lv=$(cat latestversionnumber.txt)

if [[ $v -lt $lv ]]
then
  echo version is less than latest
else
  echo version is greater than or equal to latest
fi
```

Comment: With bash it is possible to replace `cat` by `<`.

Comment: `line 4: [[: 3861: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "3861")`

Comment: are the numbers "quoted" in your text file?

Comment: I noticed it was being encoded as `UTF-8 (with BOM)` instead of `UTF-8` created a new file for `versionnumber.txt` we are good to go! :D thanks for the help Jeff!